# Count number of occurrences in various lists Java

Tags: java

I've got in Java a map of this type
`Map<Group, List<Person>>`
that is a set of groups with the whole list of members.
I want to find the Person that is in the largest number of groups using streams and lambda expressions, I tried something but it wasn't successful.
Can you help me please? Thanks

Comment: You should start posting what you tried, so that people con advice you starting from that.

Comment: Does your `Person` class override `.equals()` or have some other way of identifying the same object?

Comment: That's actually a tricky question... I can do it, but it involves a really ugly reduction operation with if statements and mutable hashmaps, so it's not super-functional. It's something like `groups.values().stream.flatmap(l -> l.stream()).reduce(new HashMap<String, Integer>(), (s, m) -> { //ugly code}).entrySet.stream().sort(//more ugly code).getFirst();`

Comment: "This question appears to be off-topic" -- I disagree. This is a reasonably good programming problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need is `.flatMap()` followed by a `.collect()` which finds the frequency of each person in the overall `Map`.

Something like this:

```
Person socialButterfly = groupMap.values()
    .stream()
    .flatMap(Collection::stream)
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
    .entrySet().stream()
    .max(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
    .get().getKey();
```

[Ideone Tested](http://ideone.com/FiBzL9)

Comment: I've tested it now. It works! Make sure `Person` overrides `.equals(Object)` so that the `groupingBy` can identify people that can be classified as the same.

Comment: @YassinHajaj Thanks! :) I got really excited when I found `Map.Entry.comparingByValue()`. It's weird that I was able to do so much with so little info from the OP. The question was pretty straightforward I guess. Considering the complexity, I disagree with closing the question from other solutions.

Comment: The answer is top. But the question shows a lack of effort from OP.

Comment: Good job, @4castle! And good timing too. If you had delayed writing your answer @YassinHajaj would have helped to put this on hold w/o your answer :-)